# LARAVEL v9.21.6 plugin v0.5.2

Tags: laravel, npm, breeze

I use docker (sail) and I will use Breeze and I do everything was into the documentation

```
sail require laravel/breeze --dev
sail artisan breeze:install react
sail npm install
sail npm run dev
```

Everything was ok until I put sail npm run dev command becouse it display me error like in title of this post

```
LARAVEL v9.21.6  plugin v0.5.2
```

I don't know what plugins are involved. How can I solve this problem?

@Update

```
> dev
> vite


  VITE v3.0.3  ready in 459 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://IP:5173/

  LARAVEL v9.21.6  plugin v0.5.2

  ➜  APP_URL: http://hello.test
```

But I can't after run command

```
sail npm run watch
```

Comment: Is that actually the full error message, because it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: This is not an error, this is [output](https://github.com/laravel/vite-plugin/blob/main/src/index.ts#L161) from laravel vite plugin

Answer (score 0):

Can you try clear all cache;

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

After that enter maintenance mode;

```
php artisan down
```

Than publish again;

```
php artisan up
```